# Node JS Path checker

Tags: node.js, regex

I want to check if a string (URL path like) is in an array of paths. 
Something like this:

I have a list of valid paths

```
const allowedPaths = [
{
  path: `/resource/:objectid/property`,
  method: callFunction1
}, 
{
  path: `/another-resource/:objectid/property`,
  method: callFunction2
}]
```

if I get this `/resource/1/property` I want to callFunction1 because the path is like the first object.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a job where [regular expressions](https://javascript.info/regular-expressions) are the right tool to use.

Comment: I don't think your question phrasing makes sense personally, do you mean test whether an input string is a valid (recognised format) URL?

Comment: if the string meets the path expectation (in the example it's /resource/:objectid/property), it should call a function... my idea is to make an API proxy based on the path

Comment: So you want this: `function testPath(inputURL) { //code to see if input a format in 'allowedPaths) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a regex to parse and whenever it matches, use tat object to call the function. There are some packages available to do this job. one of it is `path-to-regexp`. The code will looks like this.

```
const {pathToRegexp} = require("path-to-regexp");

const allowedPaths = [
  {
    path: "/resource/:objectid/property",
    method: () => {console.log("firstFunction....")}
  }, 
  {
    path: "/another-resource/:objectid/property",
    method: () => {console.log("secondFunction....")}
  }];

function getFunction(path) {
  const item = allowedPaths.find(row => pathToRegexp(row.path).exec(path) != null);

  if (item) {
    return item.method;
  }
  return null;
}

getFunction('/resource/1/property')();
getFunction('/another-resource/1/property')();
```

You can also try it here.

https://repl.it/repls/IdioticMindlessPredictions

Comment: needless to say, you might need to do some null checks

Comment: Worked like charm!! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I think this is really easy enough, but maybe I don't understand the question properly:

```
function testPath(inputURL) {
     let elems  = inputURL.split(path.sep)
     allowedPaths.forEach(function(aPath) {
          let subjPath = aPath.path.split(path.sep)
          elems.forEach(function(elem, index) {
              if (subjPath[index] !== elem && elem.charAt(0) !== ":") {
                  break
              else if (elem.charAt(0) !== ":") {
                  break
              }
            return aPath.method()
          })
     })
}
```

Comment: Did I miss something?